# VBScript Turn a string into a-z A-Z 0-9

Tags: input, vbscript, replace, user-input, hta

I have a hta/VBscript script that adds users to a registry. The script takes the inputted first and last name and puts them together into an email address (Firstname.Lastname@company.com).

I want letters like å, ä, é, ô and so on to be replaced with normal, a to Z letters. Is there a simple way to do that?

I have looked at the [Replace](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_replace.asp) function but it seems it can only replace one letter and not an array of them.

I have also looked at [this function](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/506713/Replacing-special-characters-with-their-equivalent), which seems to work but seems VERY extensive to me. There must be an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBScript doesn't magically know which letter you want to map to which other letter, so you need to create the mapping yourself. I'd create the mappings as a dictionary rather than a bunch of arrays, though:

```
Set mappings = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
mappings.Add "ä", "a"
mappings.Add "â", "a"
mappings.Add "á", "a"
mappings.Add "à", "a"
...
mappings.Add "Ä", "A"
mappings.Add "Â", "A"
...

Function canonicalize(ByVal addr)
  For Each c In mappings.Keys
    addr = Replace(addr, c, mappings(c))
  Next

  Set re = New RegExp
  re.Pattern = "[^a-z0-9.@]"
  re.Global  = True
  re.IgnoreCase = True

  Canonicalize = re.Replace(addr, "")
End Function
```

The regular expression replacement at the end of the function removes all non-canon characters that weren't covered by any of the previous mappings.

You could also do this entirely with regular expressions by defining "replacement classes":

```
Set mappings = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
mappings.Add "äâáà..." , "a"
mappings.Add "ÄÂ..."   , "A"
...

Function canonicalize(ByVal addr)
  Set re = New RegExp
  re.Global = True
  re.IgnoreCase = False

  For Each c In mappings.Keys
    re.Pattern = "[" & c & "]+"
    addr = re.Replace(addr, mappings(c))
  Next

  re.Pattern = "[^a-z0-9.@]"
  re.IgnoreCase = True

  Canonicalize = re.Replace(addr, "")
End Function
```